# How do you make basic substitutions in Mathematica?

Tags: replacement

I have an equation:

```
e == m*c^2 + (1/2)*c^2*m*v^2
```

$$e==m c^2 + \frac{1}{2}c^2\space m\space v^2$$

I need to remove the $v$ variable and replace it with $p$.  I also know that $p=m\space v$.  If I multiply the second expression of this equation by $m/m$, I can get:

$$e==m c^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{c^2\space m^2\space v^2}{m}$$And then I can make the substitution $p=mv$ to get:
$$e==m c^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{c^2\space p^2}{m}$$
How do I make force Mathematica to make this substitution for me?

Comment: `/. v -> p/m` ?

Comment: Now that I see it, it looks simple.  Thank you.